# Convert Array of JSON Objects to CSV - Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have converted a simple JSON to CSV successfully.
I am facing issue , when the file contains Array of JSON Objects.
I am using `csv` module not `pandas` for converting.
Please refer the content below which is getting processed successfully and which is failing :

Sucess (When the file contains single list/array of json object ):

```
[{"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"}]
```

Fail :

```
[{"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"}]
[{"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"}]
[{"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"}]
```

The `json.loads` function is throwing exception as follows :

```
Extra data ; line 1 column 6789 (char 1234)
```

How can to process such files ?

EDIT :
This file is flushed using Kinesis Firehorse and pushed to S3.
I am using lambda to download the file and load it and transform.
so it is not a **.json** file.

Answer (score 4):

Parse each line like so:

```
with open('input.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        obj = json.loads(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your file is not valid JSON. You have to read your file line-by-line and then convert each line individually to object.

Or, you can convert your file structure like this...

```
[
  {
    "value": 0.97,
    "key_1": "value1",
    "key_2": "value2",
    "key_3": "value3",
    "key_11": "2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"
  },
  {
    "value": 0.97,
    "key_1": "value1",
    "key_2": "value2",
    "key_3": "value3",
    "key_11": "2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"
  },
  {
    "value": 0.97,
    "key_1": "value1",
    "key_2": "value2",
    "key_3": "value3",
    "key_11": "2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"
  }
]
```

and it will be a valid JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

As tanaydin said, your failing input is not valid json.  It should look something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "value":0.97,
        "key_1":"value1",
        "key_2":"value2",
        "key_3":"value3",
        "key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"
    },
    {"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"},
    {"value":0.97,"key_1":"value1","key_2":"value2","key_3":"value3","key_11":"2019-01-01T00:05:00Z"}
]
```

I assume you're creating the json output by iterating over a list of objects and calling `json.dumps` on each one.  You should create your list of dictionaries, then call `json.dumps` on the whole list instead.

```
list_of_dicts_to_jsonify = {}
object_attributes = ['value', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_11']
for item in list_of_objects:
    # Convert object to dictionary
    obj_dict = {}
    for k in object_attributes:
        obj_dict[k] = getattr(item, k) or None
    list_of_dicts_to_jsonify.append(obj_dict)

json_output = json.dumps(list_of_dicts_to_jsonify)
```